# Let $f$ be a holomorphic in $D(0,1)$, with Re$\,f(z) >0$ and $f(0)=1.$ Then $\lvert\, f'(0)\rvert\leq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, derivatives, absolute-value

Let $f:D(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function, such that

$$
\mathrm{Re} \,f(z) >0\quad \text{and}\quad f(0)=1.
$$

How to prove $\lvert\, f'(0)\rvert\leq 2 \ ?$

---

*This is now a self-answered question.*

Comment: Perhaps you mean $f(0) = i$?  Otherwise $f(0)=1$ contradicts $\text{Im} f(z) > 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I have hence edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Find a Möbius transformation $g$ that takes the right half-plane to the unit disk and $1$ to $0$. Then apply Schwarz's Lemma to $g \circ f$.

Answer (score 6):

Thank you user179549. Let $H$ denote the right plane minus y axis and define $g:H \to D(0,1)$ by $g(z) = \dfrac{z-1}{z+1}.$ It follows that $|g(f(z))| < 1, \forall z \in D(0,1), $ $g \circ f$ is holomorphic in $D(0,1)$ and $g(f(0)) =0.$ By Schwarz lemma, $|g'(f(0))||f'(0)|\leq 1,$ so $|f'(0)| \leq 2.$